# What will happen if set --num -executor with high value for Large/small data set in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to find the answer of two questions

1. In Yarn cluster environment, Let’s say If I set --num -executor 100 and we want to process large data set like 20 TB. Consider other applications are already running. What will happen when my application is started? Will application wait until it gets 100 executors or it will start?
2. Above question with small data set.

Will you please assist ?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Yarn cluster environment, Let’s say If I set --num -executor 100 and we want to process large data set like 20 TB. Consider other applications are already running. What will happen when my application is started? Will application wait until it gets 100 executors or it will start?

First Yarn Resource Manager will check whether is there any resource available for your job to run till then your job application status will be in **ACCEPTED** state. once the resources are available then your application status will go in **RUNNING** state.
if your specify  **--num -executor as 100 or 1000 executor it does not matter** .. Yarn Resource manager only launches the number of executors based on the resource availability.
**if your cluster is free and and have capability to run "N" executors then it will launch "N" otherwise it depends on the resource availability in your cluster.**

note: Yarn Schedular(Fair or Capacity) also play an important role when you are running multiple applications in cluster at same time.

Comment: Thanks kavetiraviteja for you answer . But if you are saying,  doesn't matter 100 or 1000 and executors will be launched base on the resource availability then what is the significance of this configuration setting ?

Comment: @D_Tiwari it also a way to tell resource manager that i need as many executors as possible to use most of the resource or otherwise you can find the exact number of executor you can launch using (simple calculation on cluster resources) and pass that value in command line.